# How to create columns header and its labels with QTableView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

The code below creates a simple `QTableView` with a header and three `QStandardItem`s.
**Question**: How to make its header to have three columns labeled as "Column 0", 'Column 1" and "Column 3"?

[image]

```
import os,sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
class Window(QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__() 
        header=QtGui.QHeaderView(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.setHorizontalHeader(header)
        model=QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        for i in range(3):
            model.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem('Item %s'%i))
        self.setModel(model)  
        self.show()

window=Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0,3) # three columns

model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels( [ "Column 0", "Column 1", "Column 3"] )
```

Comment: `model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels( [ "Column 0", "Column 1", "Column 3"] )` Thanks!!

Comment: yes, sorry. Also, you can use QTableWidget, might be simpler.

Comment: I have to use `model` to keep things in sync. QTableWidget doesn't support it. Thanks again!

Comment: How can you do the same but with QtCore.QAbstractTableModel?

Comment: I believe you want to implement [headerData](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QAbstractItemModel.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.headerData)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this:

```
bool QAbstractItemModel.setHeaderData (self, int section, Qt.Orientation orientation, QVariant value, int role = Qt.EditRole)
```

But it requires set the sections and orientation.

Advantage:

You can set role, for example `Qt::DecorationRole`, it allows you set images to your headers. You can combine different roles and get beautiuful results. For example, you can add simple text to image with `Qt::DisplayRole` or `Qt::EditRole`. As you can see, it is more flexible approach.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I'll try it when there is a chance.